# Cannot Find lippicv but $LD_LIBRARY_PATH lists it

Tags: linux, opencv

I have installed OpenCV on Ubuntu (I believe successfully). Upon compiling a simple project I am getting the error:

> usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lippicv

What is the problem here and what do I need to do to fix it?

Compilation:

> g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename hello_world.cpp .cpp` hello_world.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`

Relevant Information:

- `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` outputs `:/home/me/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib`
- `pkg-config --libs opencv` outputs `-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lippicv -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core`

Any advice what the heck is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I found a solution here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5852

Rebuilt with this option: -D INSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON

For me, it worked.